# What does std::vector<std::string> vec{3}; actually do?

Tags: c++, initialization, stdvector, stdstring, list-initialization

I am currently trying to understand list initialization in C++11 and I have stumbled upon this line of code: `std::vector<std::string> vec{3};` I am wondering what it is actually doing, I noticed 3 elements are created in the vector however, I am not sure why and what values these elements will be initialized with.

Edit:
I have tried running:

```
int main()
{
  std::vector<std::string> vec{3};
  std::cout<<vec.size()<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<vec[0]<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<vec[1]<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<vec[2]<<std::endl;
}
```

and I only get the output:
3

If they are default initialized shouldn't the output be: 
3
0
0
0

Comment: Each element will be default constructed. And perhaps [this `std::vector` Constructor reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) might be useful? By the way, you're using overload number 4 (unless your compiler is really old and uses pre-C++11, in which case its number 3) from the linked reference.

Comment: Is it calling (4) instead of the initializer_list c'tor because there arent any matching signature (only has (10) that takes two params)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I tried replying in the comments but couldn't add the code snippet so I have updated my question instead.

Comment: @Sekai You're constructing a vector of strings. You're printing out empty strings. Why would they be `"0"`?

Comment: The value `3` doesn't isn't a string, so it can't be used for the initializer list constructor. The only other constructor matching the argument `3` is number 4 in the overload list.

Comment: And an empty string is very different from the string `"0"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`vector<T>` has a constructor which takes a single integer; it creates a vector containing 3 default-initialized `T`s. This constructor is therefore a viable candidate constructor when you use syntax equivalent to `vector<T>{3}`.

However, the use of `{}` syntax means that any `vector<T>` constructors which take an `initalizer_list` are checked first. If the `T` in `vector<T>` was an integer type, `{3}` would map to `vector<T>`'s `initializer_list<T>` constructor.

But since `T` in this case is a `std::string`, `vector<std::string>`'s `initializer_list` constructor doesn't match an integer. So instead, the N-element constructor is called.

To avoid such things in the future, you should avoid using `{}` with containers and container-like types unless your intent is to initialize them with a sequence of elements.

> If they are default initialized shouldn't the output be:

No. A default-initialized `std::string` contains no characters. Not the "0" character, *no characters*. If you print out a string containing no characters, then you have printed out nothing.

Answer (score 3):

When you initialize a vector of strings in c++, they will default to empty strings, or `""`. If you tried to print

```
std::cout << "";
```

you would get nothing. That is essentially whats happening here. Each index is just an empty string that is printing an empty string.